# The client has been disconnected while trying to perform the connection

Tags: c#, .net-core, mqtt, mosquitto

When trying to connect to a Mosquitto MQTT queue running locally, I get the following error.

```
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The client  has been disconnected while trying to perform the connection)
 ---> System.Net.Mqtt.MqttClientException: The client  has been disconnected while trying to perform the connection
   at System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl.ConnectAsync(MqttClientCredentials credentials, MqttLastWill will, Boolean cleanSession)
```

I am using the default options when setting up the `System.Net.Mqtt.MqttClient`.

```csharp
var config = new MqttConfiguration() {
  Port = 1883
};
var client = MqttClient.CreateAsync("localhost", config).Result;
var sessionState = client.ConnectAsync(
                new MqttClientCredentials(clientId: "camerasim")).Result;
```

The following errors show up in the Mosquitto MQTT log.

```
1644497589: New connection from 172.17.0.1:56792 on port 1883.

1644497589: New client connected from 172.17.0.1:56792 as camerasim (p2, c0, k0).

1644497589: Bad socket read/write on client camerasim: Invalid arguments provided.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you are seeing is most likely the result of a [change](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/ChangeLog.txt) made in Mosquitto 2.0.12:

> Fix `max_keepalive` not applying to MQTT v3.1.1 and v3.1 connections. These clients are now rejected if their keepalive value exceeds max_keepalive. This option allows CVE-2020-13849, which is for the MQTT v3.1.1 protocol itself rather than an implementation, to be addressed.

A change made in 2.0.9 also comes into play:

> Fix `max_keepalive` option not applying to clients connecting with keepalive set to 0. Closes #2117.

These changes were made to address an issue with the MQTT protocol itself which permits a denial of service attack ([CVE-2020-13849](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-13849)).

The default value for `max_keepalive` is `65535` so this change means that attempting to connect with keep alive set to 0 (meaning no keepalive) will fail unless `mosquitto.conf` specifies `max_keepalive 0`. Unfortunately the error logged (`Bad socket read/write on client XXXXXYYYYY: Invalid arguments provided.`) does not really highlight the cause.

There are two available solutions:

- Specify `max_keepalive 0` in `mosquitto.conf` (Mosquitto 2.0.13 or later).
- When connecting specify a keep alive between 1 and 65535. In `xamarin/mqtt` this means adding `KeepAliveSecs` to your config; this [defaults to 0](https://github.com/xamarin/mqtt/blob/main/src/Client/MqttConfiguration.cs#L19).

Note that setting `KeepAliveSecs = 1` (as per your answer) will allow you to connect but is probably a little short for most users (`KeepAliveSecs = 60` may be more appropriate). e.g.

```
var configuration = new MqttConfiguration {
    Port = 1883,
    KeepAliveSecs = 60,
    WaitTimeoutSecs = 2,
};
```

*I realise that you have already found a solution to this but as it's likely to affect others I thought it was worth explaining the root cause of the issue. Many MQTT libraries default keep alive to 0 so will be impacted (e.g. Go Paho had an [issue logged](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/issues/545)).*

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully make a connection by changing the default `KeepAliveSecs` property when setting up the `MqttConfiguration`.

```csharp
var config = new MqttConfiguration() {
  KeepAliveSecs = 1,
  Port = 1883
};
```